# NetSuite Payroll transactions in SuiteTalk SOAP web service API

Tags: soap, netsuite

The NetSuite user interface shows certain payroll-related transaction types such as `Payroll Liability Cheque` and `Paycheque`, for example, in the General Ledger Report. (I've set my profile to use UK English; you may see these spelt "check" instead of "cheque".) However, when I search through all transactions in the SuiteTalk API using `stub.search(new TransactionSearchBasic())` all of these payroll transactions are missing from the list. Is there something I have to do to be able to read them? (When running my app I login as an administrator, so shouldn't have any access restrictions.)

Comment: Did you try payroll item - https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2014_2/schema/record/payrollitem.html?

Comment: And PayCheck Journal https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2014_2/schema/record/paycheckjournal.html?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, prasun. Yes I did try them. Payroll item is not a transaction record type, it is the type of items found in a sublist of, for example, PaycheckJournal records. PaycheckJournal is the only payroll-related record type that I found in the WSDL. It is not what I'm looking for. It is intended for web service integration of an external payroll application. It allows you to add journal entries into NetSuite reflecting paychecks made by the external payroll application. I am instead looking to read payroll transactions when payroll is implemented in NetSuite itself.

Comment: What is the URL that you view payroll transactions on? This might help shed light on which SuiteTalk record the data can be pulled from.